# Linear regression and gradient descend equations

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression, gradient-descent, javascript

I'm pretty new to ML and was starting out with linear regression combined with gradient descend.

This is the equation I was trying to achieve using javascript-

[image]

And this is what I came up with in js-

```
      function algorithmify(){
    let sumHDiff=hypotheses();
    if(Math.round(hypotheses())!=0){
      let sumHDiffMult=hypothesesWithMult();
      T0-=0.0001*sumHDiff/points;
      T1-=0.0001*sumHDiffMult/points;
      
      console.log(T0,T1);
    }
  }
  
  function hypotheses(){
    let sum=0;
    for(var i=0;i<points;i++){
      let hypo=T0+(T1*X[i]);
      let diff=hypo-Y[i];
      diff*=diff;
      sum+=diff;
    }
    return sum;
  }
  function hypothesesWithMult(){
    let sum=0;
    for(var i=0;i<points;i++){
      let hypo=T0+(T1*X[i]);
      let diff=hypo-Y[i];
      diff*=diff;
      mult=diff*X[i];
      sum+=mult;
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

I tried to match the code with the equation and even though I haven't done good variable naming, I'm pretty sure it is following the equation correctly.

But the result of $T0$ and $T1$ representing `theta 0` and `theta 1` first outputs very large negative numbers and after a few iterations, output $-infinity$ both times.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!
In the equation,there is no squaring the sum but idk why I added it in.

Removing that fixed the issue.
Yet I still am not sure when the data is converging